# Group or Aggregate functions (min(),max(),sum(),count(),...etc.,) cannot be used within the Group by/Order by/Where/ON clause

Tags: sql, zoho

It seems that I can not order by the count of a column which is odd because I have seen plenty of examples where the count() is used in the ORDER BY statement. I am using Zoho Analytics.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT "Lead Owner Name", "Lead Source", count("Lead Source")
FROM "Leads"
group by "Lead Owner Name", "Lead Source"
order by count("Lead Source") DESC;
```

Comment: Can you order by a column alias instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an alias:

```
SELECT "Lead Owner Name", "Lead Source", count("Lead Source") as cnt
FROM "Leads" 
GROUP BY "Lead Owner Name", "Lead Source" 
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Most databases support arbitrary expressions in the `ORDER BY`.  However, some require that the sorting expression actually be a column -- and they don't detect when a `SELECT` expression is the same as the `ORDER BY` expression.  I've hit this problem before (I think with Hive) and just thought this might work in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column number in the ORDER BY clause in Zoho Analytics. :)

```
SELECT "Lead Owner Name", "Lead Source", count("Lead Source")
FROM "Leads"
group by 1,2
order by 3 DESC
```